# DOM equivalent of jQuery .clone() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

What is a good equivalent for the jQuery `.clone()` function in regular DOM JavaScript? I performed multiple searches (on both SO and Bing) and didn't find a specific answer. I need to produce a copy of an element and all of its internal elements. The clone must have all of the elements and content of the source elements. If possible, make the solution as compact or efficient as possible.

Comment: I don't appreciate being flagged for having a "duplicate" question when the supposed duplicate question doesn't have the the operative word in the title ("clone"), didn't come up as a suggestion when I entered it, and asks specific details that the other question does not. This is clearly NOT a duplicate of the other question, even if the answer ends up being the same.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
var clonedElement = document.getElementById('id').cloneNode(true)
```

Answer (score -1):

var element= document.getElementById("myid");

var clone= element.cloneNode(true);